# exclude syslog facility from all others

Tags: logging, syslog

I'm adding some custom logging on local0 in syslog.

Writing these messages to a specific log is easy, in my syslog.conf I have

`local0.*      -/var/log/my.log`

But how can I exclude local0 from all other logs?  In my current setup, local0 messages also show up in /var/log/syslog since it's specified as

`*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog`

Do I need to go through all the other default logs and add local0.none, or is there some kind of global exclude I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In syslog I'm afraid your assumption is right, you have to do it by adding `local0.none` to each syslog line you don't want local0 in.

If you're looking for other options [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) is all in nowadays (all the cool kids love it), and will actually let you do what you're asking for (check [here](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html)).

Also [syslog-ng](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng) allows you to do what you're asking for, and have some pretty cool filtering by strings even (check [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Logs/Syslog_ng/filter_functions_with_examples.shtml)), I use it for advanced syslogging on my log collector server.

Comment: Would be great with a pointer to where in your rsyslog reference the global exclude is described.

Comment: i found this [stackexchange link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492265/222241) more helpful than the official documentation, in case someone else gets sent here from google searching for the same task using rsyslog

Answer (score 8):

The syslogd manpage states that the exclamation mark is used as a notation for excluding specified priorities, and that "You may use it intuitively as an exception specifier". The example given is

```
mail.*;mail.!=info              /usr/adm/mail
```

which would log all mail messages except those with "info" priority. So, for your problem, I'd use

```
*.*;local0.!debug;auth,authpriv.none /var/log/syslog
```

or, more readable,

```
*.*;local0.none;auth,authpriv.none /var/log/syslog
```

However, you should be aware that I was not able to test this.

Comment: interesting, isn't `mail.*;` redundant in the first example? `mail.!=info` already means everything except info.

Comment: @LogicDaemon Since this was an example from a manpage, I guess the authors explicitely used this notation to show that it's possible to exclude something after explicitely matching everything else.